# Modify instance type in AWS is failed

Tags: amazon-web-services, instancetype

I have a VM on AWS that has been deployed with a custom image.
when trying to change the instance type this msg is prompted:

```
The instance configuration for this AWS Marketplace product is not supported. Please see the AWS Marketplace site for more information about supported instance types, regions, and operating systems.
```

how can I check what is the problem? I don't have any further messages.
is there a console/log that I can check?
or even an API to check what instance types my image is suit for?

Thank's

Comment: Since AWS Marketplace product you have to check with who ever provided the AMI. Maybe they also provide some documentation on what the AMI supports.

Comment: Providing more details like what is the prodcut, what is your current type and to what you want to change can help is in troubleshooting.